# Missing Require for coinbase in greasemonkey/tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, coinbase-api

So I am trying to implement getting my address from coinbase for BTC to use on sites, but since it changes w/ ever deposit I can't just use

```
var wallet = 'walletaddress'
```

(as I want to not have my address followed (been hacked before cause of it)

So I've gone over to coinbases API area and pulled the following code:

```
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;

var client = new Client({'apiKey': 'API KEY',
                         'apiSecret': 'API SECRET'});

client.getAccount('82de7fcd-db72-5085-8ceb-bee19303080b', function(err, account) {
  account.createAddress(null, function(err, address) {
    console.log(address);
  });
});
```

(this is EXACTLY their code, as no info is mine)

But when I throw it into Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey....

I get "'require' is undefined" for

```
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
```

After about 2 hours of searching google and here, I thought I would just ask and see if anyone has any info on this?

Comment: You are trying to use Node.js code from Tampermonkey. That will never work.  You must do your own OAuth2 in plain javascript. Search around for that.

Comment: Closely related, possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273846/javascript-ajax-to-coinbase-api-getting-request-timestamp-expired-error-using